# How to create a table dynamically with a field of main table as its name in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database, dynamic

I have a main table namely events with eventid as one of its attribute. The need is that whenever an eventid is added as a field for eventid, I need to dynamically create a new table with the field entry as new table name.Also I have similar columns for every table going to create.

For example, if I entered abc126 as eventid, I need to create a table named abc126 and have attributes such as

```
Username, Password, Fullname, Addresses, contact, etc..
```

Here the attributes should be same for every table created.

I.e If I add another eventid as xyz222,then a xyz222 table should be created with the above mentioned attributes. How can I do this?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning - what have YOU tried? Where is the code YOU wrote as your baseline? This is an online community to HELP people, not to become voluntary freelancers.

Comment: You should not do this, you need to properly design your database structure by having a single users table with reference to which event they are aligned with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you insert a record in your events table with some value like 'abc126' as an eventid,

Simply execute the next query like this

```
CREATE TABLE `abc126` LIKE `events`;
```

This will create a new table as 'abc126' with structure/attributes similiar to your events table.
If you wish to have the attributes similiar to any other table , change `events` to that table name

```
CREATE TABLE `abc126` LIKE `tablename`;
```

If you want to further modify the new table being created with limited attributes check the mysql 'CREATE TABLE' options.

Comment: Thanks alot for ur contributions